# Security of logging in with phone number only, plus SMS code

Tags: php, security, twilio, two-factor-authentication

I am building a cross-platform app and using PHP and MySQLi. Users sign up with either their Facebook account or phone number. If they choose phone number, they enter their number and an SMS is sent containing the verification code. The user enters the code and an API token is sent back to be used across the API requests. Tinder (for example) is this way.

I am considering Twilio for the verification.

My issue comes down to the security of this login process. Can a malicious user just rapid-fire the login request that creates a verification code over and over again... sending plenty of SMS and costing me a fortune on my Twilio account? Should I only allow so many attempts? Can a bot just eventually guess the code?

What is the security behind Tinder's API?

Answer (score 1):

things to consider:

1- limit request per phone number

2- limit request per user (by ip)

3- use captcha (only after second attempts to keep your app user friendly)

4- use honeypots

"can a bot guess the code?"
verification codes should have a time constraint. after like 2 mins they should be invalid. time constraint and request limiting should make it very very unlikely for a bot to guess the code.

if you are using laravel it already have [rate limiting middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting) (limit by ip).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I agree with all the things that Shalior says in their answer, so I'm not going to reiterate that.

What I wanted to share was this article on [falsehoods programmers believe about phone numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md). It is a good reminder that phone numbers don't necessarily uniquely define a user, and worth keeping in mind if this is your intention for a passwordless login.